# Highlight submit button when focus on input field in html

Tags: html, css

I am new in front-web development. I am creating a subscription form. I need to highlight the subscribe button when user clicks on the input field. How can I do it by using CSS? I don't want to use JavaScript. My HTML code is below:

HTML:

```
<form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Your email ID">   
     <input type="submit" class="submit_button" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

Comment: How do want to highlight the button? Do you want it to be a different color, have bolder text, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/pagosokipu/edit?html,css,js,output

required css

`input[type='text']:focus ~ input[type='submit']{
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #555;
}`

read about ~ selector here .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors